# ImageView not centering

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to put the image above of my `LinearLayout` but I can not add the attribute to do that, now my layout looks like :

[image]

My goal is to get this :

[image]

The goal is to put the image a little bit centered, but trying avoiding margins and dirty code...

Here's my `layout.xml`

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">


    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView
            android:id="@+id/gifImageView"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_270sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_240sdp" />
    </FrameLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/section_label"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            tools:text="Page One" />

        <TextView
            style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:id="@+id/tv_description"
            android:alpha="0.7"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Also I'd like to wrap the image adding the `wrap_content` but if I do this, the image puts on the top and small

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you wont change your main layout as relative layout then try out below code.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/ll">

        <pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView
            android:id="@+id/gifImageView"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_270sdp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />
    </FrameLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/section_label"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            tools:text="Page One" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_description"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:alpha="0.7"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Otherwise try out this code.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/ll">

    <pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView
        android:id="@+id/gifImageView"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_270sdp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />
</FrameLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/section_label"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        tools:text="Page One" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_description"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:alpha="0.7"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
</LinearLayout></RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: My pleasure... Stuart2041